# Hyperledger Composer Network Deployment Issue: Card Not Found

Tags: hyperledger-composer

Currently working through the [Hyperledger Composer Basics tutorial Part 3](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-deploy-interact-extend-local-blockchain-network-with-hyperledger-composer/index.html) using the cli. I was able to successfully install the prerequisites and create a Business Card Network Card, but am stuck at the following step of network deployment.

When I attempt to start the network, I get a "Card Not Found" error.

I am in the correct directory and have looked at the v0.20 documentation (the tutorial is in v0.15) but have been unable to sort this out given that I am fairly new to UNIX and the cli.

My latest attempt at using the correct code:

```
composer network start -f dist/perishable-network.bna -n perishable-network -A admin -S adminpw -c PeerAdmin@h1fv1 -f networkadmin.card -V v0.20.2
```

Tried so far:

- I have tried exporting the admin card to h1fv12, but this did not resolve the issue.
- Tried removing all the docker images and re-launching the network from scratch.
- Tried re-downloading the source files.
- Tried a number of different combinations for the -v -c and -f to see what would work.

Much appreciated if you have any advice!

Comment: hi there -  I'd imagine (but you didn't say which card or which step) its because you didn't import the appropriate business network card (?? `admin@iot-perishable-network` of `shipper@iot-perishable-network` etc ?? ) - probably the admin card created from the `composer network start` command at a guess - and then tried to use that card in one of the tutorial's steps. Suggest to retrace your steps (you can review your cmdline history too?)  and see what's missing

Comment: Actually - I also notice that tutorial uses `composer network deploy` - which is obsolete (its using Composer v0.15 - so you may want to look at the [Developer tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/developer-tutorial) for guidance on correct commands (eg `composer network install` instead of `deploy` then `composer card import` of admin card then `composer network ping` then `composer network start` etc etc) -

Answer (score 2):

Re-execute the command, but correct the PeerAdmin card name.

The default name is "PeerAdmin@h**l**fv1" and NOT "PeerAdmin@h**1**fv1"

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot one command, just follow these instructions:

1. Go to `fabric-tools` OR `fabric-dev-servers` directory
2. run script file: `./createPeerAdminCard.sh`

This will create PeerAdmin card, so now you can access the fabric network by using that card.

Now Run command to start the network.